# Is this an expected behavior with return keyword on JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was on the verge of pulling all of my hair today over a silly mistake. The thing is that I am not sure if this is an expected behavior.

With my habits on C#, I have written the following javascript code and tried to understand what is going wrong because it didn't return anything and even didn't write any error into the console:

```
this.fullName = ko.computed(function () {

    return
        this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();

}, this);
```

Then (after half an hour), I changed the code a below and it worked:

```
this.fullName = ko.computed(function () {

    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();

}, this);
```

Is this an expected behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. It's the implicit semicolon.

Here's similar situation with explanations: http://premii.com/lab/js_implicit_semicolon_and_return.php

In short: your first snippet is interpreted as:

```
this.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
    return;
    this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
}, this);
```

Comment: well, another proof that JavaScript is not C# and it is a really "f"ed up language. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes [ECMA Spec](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9), which is the Javascript spec, defines the behavior like this

> Certain ECMAScript statements (empty statement, ... **return statement**, and throw statement) must be terminated
>   with semicolons. Such semicolons may always appear explicitly in the
>   source text. **For convenience**, however, such **semicolons may be omitted**
>   from the source text in certain situations. These situations are
>   described by saying that **semicolons are automatically inserted** into
>   the source code token stream in those situations.

Further more

> When a continue, break, return, or throw token is encountered and a
>   LineTerminator is encountered before the next token, a semicolon is
>   automatically inserted after the continue, break, return, or throw
>   token.
>
> An **Expression in a return** or throw statement **should start on the same
>   line as the return or throw token.**

And they have given an **example** of:

The source

```
return
a + b
```

is transformed by automatic semicolon insertion into the following:

```
return;
a + b;
```

---

So your first code will be interpreted as:

```
return;
        this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
```

with the automatically added semi colon at the end of return.

---

So the spec gives practical advice to face these situations in general javascript:

> A postfix **++** or **--** operator should appear on the same line as its
>   operand.
>
> An Expression in a **return** or **throw** statement should start on the same
>   line as the return or throw token.
>
> A Identifier in a **break** or **continue** statement should be on the same
>   line as the break or continue token.

Comment: I really don't know who suggested the idea of **semicolons may be omitted** but it is obvious to me that he was high when he did that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Javascript doesn't need a semicolon at the end of the line to end the statement. In this case, it simply returns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, Semicolons in javascript tend to be optional, So there is no exact way to differentiate the complete statement only using semicolons. Check out this book which I hear is a great resource for JS , The good parts of javascript by douglas crockford.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a feather which is **Automatic semicolon insertion**, which is not good, you should not depend on it and add semicolon when a statement finishes.

In you case, javascript add `;` to the `return` statement. so it is same as:

```
return;
this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
```