# jQuery Autocomplete issue with displaying JSON source

Tags: jquery, json

Following is my jQuery code:

```
$("#destinations").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/contactApi.do?&callback=?", 
          { 'contactMobile': request.term, maxRows: 12, style: "full" }, 
          function(data) {
              if(data.ApiResponse){
                  var x = $.map(data.ApiResponse, function(v, i){
                      console.log(v)
                      return {
                          label: v.Mobile + ' - ' + v.Name, 
                          v: v.Name
                      }
                  });
                  response(x);
              }
          }
        );        
    }
})
```

I can observe through FireBug that the following JSON response is created as the result of typing a mobile number like 123...

```
{"ApiResponse":{"Status":1000,"TransactionId":"","Data":{"Contacts":[{"Email":"","Mobile":"123456","Name":"john"}]},"Operation":"api","ResponseTime":"2013-02-05T16:08:33+11:00","StatusText":"Success","RequestTime":"2013-02-05T16:08:33+11:00","Object":"Contact"}}
```

This shows that the jQuery part works probably fine, but no drop down appears below my input area to display the filtered results. Is there something wrong with my script or JSON format?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

from JqueryUI autocomplete API [Autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

> The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will
>   be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item. If
>   just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you
>   provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the
>   label.

should be like this.

```
return 
     {    label: v.Mobile + ' - ' + v.Name,,
          value: v.Name
     }
```

Comment: I think single `return` will make the code below not executed.

Comment: as autocomplete expects in the form of array. do read api. it will work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750129/is-this-an-expected-behavior-with-return-keyword-on-javascript please see this.

Comment: thats different context. that for knockoutJS. i used above code for youtube api. it worked for me

Comment: Nah still no results shows up . Don't u think the JSON format is not right ?